# Getting past an AJAX form using Python Requests

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, python-requests

I've been trying to get past the form page on http://dq.ndc.bsnl.co.in/bsnl-web/residentialSearch.seam using the python Requests module.

The problem I'm guessing is the AJAX in the form field. And I really have no clue about how to go about sending a request with Python Requests for that.
I know that this can be done through Selenium, but I need it done through requests.

Here's my current code:

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0'
           }
payload = {
    "residential": "residential",
    "residential:j_id12": "",
    "residential:firstField": 'a',
    "residential:criteria1": "3",
    "residential:city": "ASIND",
    "residential:button1": "residential:button1",
    "residential:suggestionBoxId_selection": "",
    "javax.faces.ViewState": "j_id1"

}
with requests.Session() as s:
    # print s.headers
    print s.get('http://dq.ndc.bsnl.co.in/bsnl-web/residentialSearch.seam')
    print s.headers
    print s.cookies
    resp = s.post(
        'http://dq.ndc.bsnl.co.in/bsnl-web/residentialSearch.seam',
        data=payload, headers=headers)

    print resp.text
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get past"? If viewing it in the browser, does it redirect you?

Comment: Well, yeah.. By getting past i mean getting to the next page after the form submit.
I can't seem to do it through requests though. I can't understand what parameters i should be passing through to the form.

Comment: IIRC that happens because of a redirect in the browser. HTTP requests are sent by a request-per-request basis. You don't automatically request more if they want you to. Once you get past this and succeed, try going through the process in your browser and see what headers and cookies are needed to request the next page by itself. Then the next, then the next.

Comment: I've already done that. I've got a cookie in my session too.
And this is how i've generally been submitting forms to pages.
The only problem with this one seems to be the AJAX in the form.
The form action POST's to http://dq.ndc.bsnl.co.in/bsnl-web/residentialSearch.seam. But thats the part i can't get working yet.
The same kind of logic works on most other sites though.
What could be wrong with this one?

Comment: I'm not sure! Maybe someone else will come along. I'll upvote the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty near to the full solution. First you need the `AJAXREQUEST` in the payload to start the search and then follow the redirect to the first results page. The next pages you get with more requests. Only problem: there is no real end-of-pages mark, it starts over with the first page again. So I have to look into the contents for `Page x of y`.

```
import re
import requests
import requests.models

# non-standard conform redirect:
requests.Response.is_redirect = property(lambda self: (
    'location' in self.headers and (
        self.status_code in requests.models.REDIRECT_STATI or
        self.headers.get('Ajax-Response', '') == 'redirect'
)))

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0'
}
payload = {
    "AJAXREQUEST": "loader2",
    "residential": "residential",
    "residential:j_id12": "",
    "residential:firstField": 'a',
    "residential:criteria1": "3",
    "residential:city": "ASIND",
    "residential:button1": "residential:button1",
    "residential:suggestionBoxId_selection": "",
    "javax.faces.ViewState": "j_id1"

}

with requests.Session() as s:
    print s.get('http://dq.ndc.bsnl.co.in/bsnl-web/residentialSearch.seam')
    print s.headers
    print s.cookies
    resp = s.post(
        'http://dq.ndc.bsnl.co.in/bsnl-web/residentialSearch.seam',
        data=payload, headers=headers)

    while True:
        # do data processing
        for l in resp.text.split("subscriber');")[1:]: print l[2:].split('<')[0]

        # look for next page
        current, last = re.search('Page (\d+) of (\d+)', resp.text).groups()
        if int(current) == int(last):
            break

        resp = s.post('http://dq.ndc.bsnl.co.in/bsnl-web/resSrchDtls.seam',
            data={'AJAXREQUEST':'_viewRoot',
                'j_id10':'j_id10',
                'javax.faces.ViewState':'j_id2',
                'j_id10:PGDOWNLink':'j_id10:PGDOWNLink',
            }, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's perfect! :)
Could you explain to me a little more about what you did with the property please? :)

Comment: The property substitutes the original `Request.is_redirect`, which does not understand `Ajax-Response`.

Comment: But how does one get to this answer by themselves?

Comment: So, you have to look at the original definition of `is_redirect` and modify it accordingly.

Comment: But in Chrome Developer tools, i didn't see a redirect in 'docs' section of the 'Network' tab. When there should have been 3 'docs' to trace, i only saw two of them.
Although, it did indeed redirect.
I didn't see the redirect in the 'doc'.

Comment: because it's a JavaScript redirect.